# How do I select a column into @variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a stored procedure and my goal for the user to input either a single variable, multiple or all in terms of region.

I am trying to set my variable to all values in a column for region

```
DECLARE @REGION TABLE
(
REGION VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO
@REGION
SELECT * FROM Region_Table

DECLARE @REGION VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @REGION = ''

    IF ( @REGION = '' )
        OR ( @REGION = NULL ) 
        SELECT  @REGION = 'ALL AREAS'  

Select * from #table
    WHERE   Region = @Region
            OR @Region = 'ALL AREAS'
```

I want my region parameter to return a single region, multiple, or all

Comment: I'm lost.  Is `@REGION` a table or a scalar?  What is being passed into the stored procedure?

Comment: It may be best if you edit your question and supply some sample data and desired results.

Comment: Beside your main problem, we have other more important problem here. What is @region? is it a table or a variable? We need to know this to answer your question, otherwise we might be lost in the question!

Answer (score 0):

To get all columns in a row into a variable use this approach:

```
declare @table_variable table(all_columns varchar(max));

insert into @table_variable(all_columns)
select column1 + column2 + column3 from table1;
```

Note that you cannot use SELECT * (select all columns) to insert into a single column in table variable. SELECT * is generally considered a bad practice, it is better to name the columns.

If some columns are not varchar type you'll need to cast it like this:

```
select cast(column1 as varchar(100)) + cast(column2 as varchar(5)) from table1;
```

When you are checking for NULLs use "IS NULL", not "= NULL", For example

```
IF(@variable IS NULL)
```

Finally, variable names have to be unique, you cannot declare two @region variables in the same batch.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you want to use one variable to handle input either a single variable, multiple or all in terms of region, so one why is to declare a variable and use a comma separated approach.

Your input variable will be as follow:-

```
Declare @Region varchar(100)='A,B,C' --3 regions comma seperated 
--Declare @Region varchar(100)='A' -- or one only  
--Declare @Region varchar(100)=NULL -- or null for all,
```

And I will assume you have a region table that have other columns that you would like to return, so Im going to assume a table and some data for testing. (you will not this step)

```
Declare @RegionTable Table (RegionId int,Region varchar(50), otherdata varchar(100))
insert into @RegionTable values 
(1,'A','AAAA'),
(2,'B','BBBB'),
(3,'C','CCCC'),
(4,'D','DDDD'),
(5,'E','EEEE'),
(6,'F','FFFF')
```

Now we need a select that will handle one variable, multiple or all. this will help:-

```
Select * from @RegionTable r where Region in (select cs.[Value] from  STRING_SPLIT (@Region, ',') cs ) or @Region is null
```

The results will be for multiple as below:-

```
RegionId    Region  otherdata
1   A   AAAA
2   B   BBBB
3   C   CCCC
```